# Visual Code constantly changes included files in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Since a few versions, Visual Code constantly messes up my tsconfig.json by adding individual files to the include array when I add or rename files in my project.

Is there any setting to tell VC to NOT do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TypeScript` extension has a setting that updates imports on file move, this might be the culprit.

> **Typescript › Update Imports On File Move: Enabled**
>
> Enable/disable automatic updating of import paths when you rename or move a file in VS Code. Requires using TypeScript 2.9 or newer in the workspace.

Setting `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` to `never` will stop it from adding the files to `include`. You can also set it to `prompt` if you want to be asked.

Comment: @JerryGreen Setting it to `never` will make it work. I've updated the answer to reflect the changes in this setting.

Comment: Important to note that the question is about preventing VS Code from updating tsconfig.json specifically, and while this answer does do that, it also disables _all_ automatic updates, including updating imports in other .ts source files.